# UFW Not Blocking Anything (and Not Using Docker)

Tags: 18.04, ufw, vps

System: Ubuntu 18.04 on VPS.

UFW not doing anything. It's well activated, I've even reloaded the rules.

For testing, I set the following rules:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     DENY IN     Anywhere
22/tcp                     LIMIT IN    Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

I can still access the web server on port 80

Note: I've upgraded recently from 16.04 to 18.04 LTS while keeping my UFW rules, but even before that I could access the web server without even allowing HTTP and HTTPS.

I know order is important when dealing with UFW and I reload UFW every time to make sure rules are taken into account, but obviously UFW seems to be useless for me.

Comment: As I said, I upgraded to 18.04 and, apparently, the culprit was `/etc/ufw/before{,6}.rules` that was a bit outdated with regard to the new UFW version installed with Ubuntu 18.04 – I fixed the issue with a `cp before.rules.ucf-dist before.rules` and reinstalled my custom settings in this updated file version. The extension `.ucf-dist` was brought with the upgrade.

Comment: Could you please tell more about the settings? I have a similar problem.

Comment: In fact, the problem was, for me, twofold: the fact I inserted [this filter](http://blog.lavoie.sl/2012/09/protect-webserver-against-dos-attacks.html) (in _before.rule_), and my ignorance (not being able to interpret correctly _iptables_ rules). Apparently, this filter overrides the rules set with _ufw_ command when dealing with HTTP(S) ports. So, for example, a `ufw deny http` will happily be ignored because [the filter](http://blog.lavoie.sl/2012/09/protect-webserver-against-dos-attacks.html)—if my understanding is right—takes precedence over the command line definition.

Comment: I guess these rules in the [filter](http://blog.lavoie.sl/2012/09/protect-webserver-against-dos-attacks.html) are the reasons:  `-A ufw-before-input -p tcp --dport 80   -j ufw-http` and `-A ufw-before-input -p tcp --dport 443  -j ufw-http`

Comment: By the way, an [update](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jackygurui/c07840938e2377682972/raw/0380005912107648b01e4903813f2fddeaa3d4af/ufw_http_https_rules) of the filter.